# Why is my table row to dialog binding failing?

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

I'm trying to recreate this example using a JSView:

https://embed.plnkr.co/BA9T4Z0QdsZrqkooWTs2/

The data is bound to the table, and then when clicking a row, it binds the row data to the dialog box.

I was trying to follow this example in my own project, but I could not make it work, so I then tried to recreate the example above step by step in a JSView.

https://embed.plnkr.co/jvaQyVgvjNP261lVBFaz/  (ignore the App.view.xml file).

On Line 34 of my controller `getBindingContext("userList")` is undefined, even though I'm using the correct model name.

This contrasts with Line 31 of the example's controller where `getBindingContext("list")` returns an object.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the XML example, item press is set on the column list item, in the JS example it's set on the table. `getSource()` then returns the table instead of the line. You can fix it by changing the press event:

```
var oTable = new sap.m.Table({
    id: "UserTable",
    columns: [
        new sap.m.Column({
            header: new sap.m.Label({
                text: "User ID"
            })
        }),
        new sap.m.Column({
            header: new sap.m.Label({
                text: "Name"
            })
        })          
    ]
});

var template = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
    type: "Active",
    visible: true,
    press: [oController.onItemPress, oController],
    cells: [
        new sap.m.Text({
            text: "{userList>Userid}"
        }),
        new sap.m.Text({
            text: "{userList>Name}"
        })
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually you don't have to change the event, also using `itemPress` event on the `Table` is fine. The parameters are just different. To get the selected item and further its context, use:

```js
event.getParameter("listItem"); // returns: pressed list item
```

instead of

```js
event.getSource(); // returns: source control that fired the event (here: sap.m.Table)
```

[More info on the `itemPress` event](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.ListBase#events/itemPress)